# matplotlib .ps output truncated

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm plotting a `matplotlib.subplots` using `plt.savefig()`
all other formats generate correct outputs. Only when I save it as .ps file, a truncated graph is generated. I tried set plt.tight_layout() but it does not work.

[image: sample]

here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

v_x = np.random.randint(0, 80000, 30000)
v_y = v_x # the x, y cordinate of the dots.

f,axes = plt.subplots(5,5,figsize = (40,40))
for row in range(5):
    for col in range(5):
        print(row,col)

        axes[row,col].set_yticklabels([])
        axes[row,col].set_xticklabels([])

        if row > col:
            axes[row,col].axis('off')
        else:
            axes[row,col].set_xlim(0,len(v_x))
            axes[row,col].set_ylim(0,len(v_y))


            axes[row,col].scatter(v_x,v_y, c = '#000000', s=(72./300)**2, marker = 's', edgecolor= '')
f.savefig('{}'.format('test.ps'), facecolor='w', bbox_inches='tight', dpi = 300)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try getting rid of

`figsize = (40, 40)`

It looks like your figure is getting truncated by the figsize argument.

Comment: Yes, but deleting this parameter would make all my subplots squished together. Is there any solution that allows me to set the figsize